# Google Analytics Tracking ID

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I see 2******* as my tracking ID in my admin section, but if I look at my source code, I see 1*******  I feel like my web developer messed up.  Am I right?

Is there ANYWAY that the 1****** is correct?  How I can find out what website this number is for?

I just want to be thorough before I confront my developer.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Besides a confrontation over a potentially wrong value, you should ask why he hard coded this value in the source rather than using a config file or writing it to the database.

Comment: If this is not your account id there is no feasible way to find out who it belons to (of course you could always send a tracking call to that id with your telephone number in it and a note asking to call you back :-) ). If the ID in the page is different from the id in your account then no, it cannot be right. If you want to make extra sure look at the realtime reports while browsing your site, your pageviews should so up there if everything is correctly set up (which it apparently isn't).